# Impossible to initialize rosdep

Tags: kinect, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ros-kinect (ubuntu 16.04), when I do sudo rosdep init I see:

```
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

I tried to make proxy server, used sudo -E rosdep init, no results. Is website really down? When it will be fixed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239303/impossible-to-initialize-rosdep/) by [VitalyPesternikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/27463/vitalypesternikov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-12**:
Does `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` work (ie: you get the file contents)?

**Comment by [VitalyPesternikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/27463/vitalypesternikov/) on 2016-07-12**:
I tried. The result is:
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.36.133|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied
Unable to establish SSL connection.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-12**:
It would seem it is impossible to open an SSL secured connection to the github servers from wherever you are. That is most likely the reason `rosdep` can't download the files it needs, not because the server is down. I'd try to solve the `wget` issue, `rosdep` will probably start working then too.

**Comment by [VitalyPesternikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/27463/vitalypesternikov/) on 2016-07-13**:
It works now. Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-13**:
So what did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I had been facing the same issue of
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.

This error is because of your system date & time settings. I corrected my systems date and time settings and rosdep init worked.

---

Originally posted by [Shoeb Ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/33157/shoeb-ahmed/) with karma: 41 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0